# Why doesn't *ngFor need brackets?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, ngfor

I am new to the Angular framework, and have recently been introduced to the attribute `*ngFor=""`.

As I have learned, this takes the same parameters as an JavaScript `for()` loop... And therefore, `*ngFor="let item of itemCollection"`. But, in contrast to other directives, `*ngFor` does not require `[]` around it to be treated as code.

[This documentation page](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-input-variables) suggests that the `hero` attribute needs `[]` around it for the value to be treated as code, and returning the value of `"hero"`:

```
<app-hero-detail *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [hero]="hero"></app-hero-detail>
```

Why is it so? The `*ngFor` is also evaluated, but does not need the `[]` obviously... Is it the `*` prefix that indicates that the value must always be treated as code or what?

Comment: Because it's a [_structural_ directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives), and none of those do, because they have the ability to mutate the node on which they are bound (repeat, render into dom, etc), whereas property bindings don't. TL;DR it's a convention the Angular folk decided on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To begin you must first understand that the bracket notation `[]`is used for [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-) in Angular.

I will use the example code you provided to help explain this:

`<app-hero-detail *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [hero]="hero"></app-hero-detail>`

In this case the `[hero]` in `[hero]="hero"` is an example of property binding in which the data will flow one-way from data source (the component) to the view (the HTML).  The property `hero` you will find was defined as in input property of that component using the [@Input decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Input).

**Which brings us to your question:**

> Why doesn't *ngFor need brackets?

The answer is exactly what you thought. You do not need to use [bracket notation] for the `*ngFor` because of the existence of the asterisk (*). The asterisk is Angular short hand notation (or syntatical sugar) that allows developers to write cleaner, easier to understand and maintain code. Beneath the sheets, when the Angular compiler "desugars" your code it will turn out looking something like this:

```
<template [ngFor]="let hero of heroes">
     <div></div>
 </template>
```

From there the Angular compiler will further "desugar" your code to something like this:

```
<template ngFor let-hero="$implicit" [ngForOf]="heros">
   <div>...</div>
 </template>
```

So in conclusion you can see that [ngFor Structural Directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) ultimately is treated like any other property that requires property binding. However, on account of it being a built in directive Angular provided us with a much cleaner to use shorthand notation. Unlike the `hero` property which we created and defined ourselves, therfore requiring us to use the bracket notation explicitly in the HTML. Don't forget even though you can use the bracket notation with structural directives you should [always prefer the asterisk](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#prefer-the-asterisk--syntax).

Answer (score 1):

Brackets [x] is used for property binding while (x) is used for event binding.

While *ngFor,*ngIf are directives and not bindings, they have given such syntax.